# What button do I press to flag for undelete?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, flagging

I recently had an answer deleted. I also got a comment, saying:

> (...) You can improve it by following the guidelines mentioned [here]. Feel free to flag it for review for undeletion once you've done so.

There are four buttons under my answer: `share` `edit` `undelete` `flag` but it's not obvious which one to press to *flag* for review for *undeletion* since two buttons have those words. `undelete` might mean undelete without review, while pressing `flag` when there's an undelete-button right next to it feels wrong. If this is a stock comment, maybe clarify that.

Comment: Did you try to press the undelete button to see what happen?

Comment: @Noon If that does undelete without review, and the comment told me to flag for review, that seems very rude.

Comment: Well then, use the flag button, choose "in need of moderator intervention" and write something like "I have edited my question, could you please undelete it?". When an answer is deleted by a mod, it's the way to go. In this case, it's a question but I think it doesn't change much (they use the same comment in both cases).

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for bringing it to our attention!

The right button to press is the **flag** button. You can select the option "in need of moderator intervention", and then write a note there explaining that you would like it considered for undeletion. The flag will show up in the moderator queue so we can take a look at your post.

If you try pressing the "undelete" button, it won't actually work - I think you'll get an error message. Since your post was deleted by a moderator, only a moderator can undelete it. If you're interested, [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) talks more about how deleting and undeleting works on Stack Exchange.

Comment: The undelete button shows this popup: Vote to undelete this post? (5 votes remaining). Does that count as working?

Comment: That's a confirmation window, I think the error  shows up after you click OK on it.

Comment: Yep, you're right, thanks for clarifying.